# I don't get this simple for-loop exercise

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, max, min

I have to write a program that calculates and displays the highest and second highest value entered by te user. The program must also work with zero or one values entered.

Here are some sample runs:

```
enter a value or 'stop' -3.2
enter a value or 'stop' -5.6
enter a value or 'stop' 0.5
enter a value or 'stop' 0.3
enter a value or 'stop' stop
the highest value = 0.5
the second highest value = 0.3
```

and

```
enter a value or 'stop' stop
the highest value could not be calculated
the second highest value could not be calculated
```

So i got a code, but it only gives me the minimum and the maximum. 
all i got so far is this:

```
minimum = None
maximum = None
a = int(input("Enter a value or 'stop': "))
while True:
    a = input("Enter a value or stop: ")
    if a == 'stop':
        break
    try:
        number = int(a)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue
    if minimum is None or number < minimum:
        minimum = number
    if maximum is None or number > maximum:
        maximum = number
print('Maximum= ', maximum)
print('Minimum= ', minimum)
```

Would be awesome if someone could help me out!

Comment: You are taking decimal point values in and converting them to `int` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
value_list = list()
while True:
    a = input("Enter a value or stop: ")
    if a == 'stop':
        break
    else:
        try:
            value_list.append(float(a))
        except:
            print("Invalid input")
            continue
sorted_list = sorted(value_list)
if len(sorted_list) > 0:
    print('the highest value = ', sorted_list[-1])
else:
    print('the highest value could not be calculated')
if len(sorted_list) > 1:
    print('the second highest value = ', sorted_list[-2])
else:
    print('the second highest value could not be calculated')
```

This should work. You might want to handle float/int scenarios

So, the code actually uses Python list to store the input values in the form of float. Once the user enters stop, we are sorting the values in the list in the ascending order and finally displaying only the top two values i.e at index -1 and -2. Enjoy!

Comment: Thankyou so much for your fast help! Really helped me!!

Answer (score 0):

As @rkta said, you don't need line 3 (as the program will ask the same question twice when you start it up).

You only need to alter your code slightly to get your desired program. Instead of using this block:

```
if minimum is None or number < minimum:
    minimum = number
if maximum is None or number > maximum:
    maximum = number
```

Use this block:

```
if highest is None or number > highest:
        highest = number
elif second_highest is None or number > second_highest:
        second_highest = number
```

Obviously you will need to set highest and second_highest to None at the beginning of your program, and change your print statements at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I add my two cents:

```
# declare a list
inputs = []

while True:
    a = input("Enter a value or stop: ")
    if a == 'stop':
        break
    try:
        # check if input is float or integer
        if isinstance(a, int) or isinstance(a, float):
            # append number to the list
            inputs.append(a)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue

# sort list  
inputs = sorted(inputs)

# print result if list has at least two values
if len(inputs) >= 2:
    # cut the list to the last two items
    maxs = inputs[-2:]
    print 'Max 1 = ',  maxs[1]
    print 'Max 2 =',  maxs[0]
else:
    print 'not enough numbers'
```